# gss_inquire_cred returns GSS_S_BAD_MECH

Tags: linux, gssapi

The ***gss_acquire_cred*** with default arguments always returns ***GSS_S_BAD_MECH***. 
Anyone who got this working? or have tips?

OS is Redhat Linux 8.0 (Ootpa) and Kerberos 5 version 1.16.1 is installed.

I am using the following code:

````
......
gss_cred_id_t *server_creds;

maj_stat = gss_acquire_cred(&min_stat, GSS_C_NO_NAME , GSS_C_INDEFINITE ,
                              GSS_C_NULL_OID_SET, GSS_C_ACCEPT,
                              server_creds, NULL, NULL);
  if (maj_stat != GSS_S_COMPLETE)
  {
    switch (maj_stat)
    {
    case GSS_S_BAD_MECH:
      mydbgU("An unavailable mechanism has been requested.");
      break;
    case GSS_S_BAD_NAMETYPE:
      mydbgU("AThe type contained within the desired_name parameter is not supported.");
      break;
    case GSS_S_BAD_NAME:
      mydbgU("AThe value supplied for desired_name parameter is ill formed.");
      break;
    case GSS_S_CREDENTIALS_EXPIRED:
      mydbgU("AThe credentials could not be acquired because they have expired.");
      break;
    case GSS_S_NO_CRED:
      mydbgU("ANo credentials were found for the specified name.");
      break;
    case GSS_S_FAILURE:
      mydbgU("GSS_S_FAILURE");
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
    return -1;
  }```
````

Comment: Use KRB5_TRACE to find the cause

Comment: My program gets  GSS_S_BAD_MECH, how would KRB5_TRACE help?

Comment: It's show what MIT Kerberos is doing, thus it could help to resolve the issue.

Comment: when i run "./gss-1.0.3/src/gss -l" I get "Found 0 supported mechanisms."

Comment: What is GSS 1.0.3? This is not MIT Kerberos.

Comment: This is the library I am using for gssapi? Which other alternatives are available?

Comment: I don't know where you have got this from, get the source code from GitHub krb5/krb5.